# Expected value of exponential random variable

Tags: random-variables

If an exponential random variable, X, has failure rate  λ, what is E[X|X<λ]?

I'm not sure how to start here. I know that E[X] = 1 / λ for an exponential random variable. Is the probability that X < λ = 1-e^(-λ*λ)?

Can I use this identity E[X] = E[X|X < c]P{X < c} + E[X|X > c]P{X > c}?

Comment: ... or *Cross Validated* (http://stats.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: As others have stated, you've posted this question on the wrong site. However, for fun, here's how you could compute this in Mathematica: `Expectation[x \[Conditioned] x < \[Lambda], 
 x \[Distributed] ExponentialDistribution[\[Lambda]]]`

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Regarding that point, when flagging the post for migration I realized that I can only suggest math or meta as alternative sites. Actually, I have been seeing quite a few questions that would fit on Cross Validated better than math. Do you (or does anybody) know how to suggest another alternative site?

Comment: Oh, I apologize. I'll post it to math.stackexchange.

Comment: @MarcoB  Searching our Meta site, you will find discussions of this very topic, but they have not gone anywhere.

Comment: @bbgodfrey Thank you for the pointer, I'll have a look.

Comment: @MarcoB I don't fully understand the constraints on suggested migration sites, but perhaps I can flag a post for migration to *Mathematics* and to *Cross validated* because I'm a member of these and have a reputation on each.